# Google Analytics UTM Tracking for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-analytics, windows-phone

Is there a way to pass UTM information trough Google Analytics, similar to websites, iOS or Android? I'm using the Google Analytics SDK from CodePlex in a Windows Phone app, and I want to pass information like utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign? 
So far all I've found is a way to set the "Campaign" property to the tracker. Is UTM available for windows phone?

```
    GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().Campaign = "myCampaign";
    GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("FirstPage");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was to add them manually in GoogleAnalyticsSDK from CodePlex. Now, you have the possibility to send parameters like CampaignName, CampaignSource, CampaignMedium, CampaignID in any Windows Phone app.